# force redirecting default firebase domain to custom domain

Tags: firebase, redirect, firebase-hosting

is it possible to redirect `example.firebaseapp.com` to `example.com`? I don't want visitors to access the default firebase domain.

Comment: No, but you can link your own Domain if you own one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform a client side redirect with JavaScript.

```
if (location.host === 'example.firebaseapp.com') {
  location.href = 'https://example.com';
}
```

You'll want to think about retaining the path, query string, and fragment as well.